# How to add values to an object attribute using setattr()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to add a value to an attribute of an object. I would use the `setattribute` function but as far as I know I can then only set it to a value, but not add anything to the existing value. I can of course first call the `getattribute` function, calculate the new value and then set the attribute, but I was wondering if there is a more concise way of doing it

Edit:
The reason why I need setattribute/getattribute is because I'm building a webapp and depending on what the user answers, a different attribute needs to be accessed.

I was wondering if there was a better method, because the object I'm referring to is a sqlalchemy table. So I would need two calls to my database and would optimally only need one.

In my webapp there is are radio buttons. I get the value using
`answer = request.form['value']` and then depending on the answer, which can either be 1 2 3 4 or 5, I access a attribute.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Post your current code and maybe some more context on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "more concise" than what? In order to add `y` to `x`, you need the current value of `x`.

Comment: why not just `obj.attribute = value`?

Comment: Are you calling __setattr__ manually? Why not just reference the attribute directly?

Comment: I've added additional information to the question

Comment: Letting a web app user typing the attribute name that gets changed sounds dangerous. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: @Wups  I of course don't let the user directly fill in the attribute name :). I've added some code for clarification. Also, this is for an university project so security is not really an issue

Comment: .." this is for an university project so security is not really an issue" we'll see in 40 years.. Bankers kept MSDOS 3.1. in their basements running for over 40 years and build a cart-house on top of it. We know whereto that has led us.

Comment: @ZF007 Lol If you see my edits, I already said that my webapp was never not secure to begin with...